# ng-style not taking scope value

Tags: angularjs

I have a couple views and I'm looking to adjust the container width based on the view I'm in.

```
<!-- our main container area for the views -->
<div class="container" ng-style="{ 'width': '95%' }">
    <div class="row" style="height: 100%;">
        <!-- below is where the partial pages will replace -->
        <div style="height: 100%;" ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I hardcode the ng-style width property it works. Above I hardcode it to 95%. However, when I set it to a scope variable and set that variable inside the view's controller it doesn't work.

```
<div class="container" ng-style="{ 'width': containerWidth }">
```

Inside one of the view controllers:

```
$scope.containerWidth = '95';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be,

```
<div class="container" ng-style="{ 'width': containerWidth + 'px' }">
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/3mhxxq13/)

Comment: I use % but I tried + '%' and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Would this be because the container is a higher level than the view/controller and therefore the scope variable?

Comment: Yes, when I set the $scope.containerWidth inside my apps controller it works, but I'm trying to set this inside my view controllers and it doesn't work. So I'm guessing the app controllers $scope is different than the view controllers $scope.

Comment: you might need to create a fiddle for that

Comment: Looks like this from the view controller did it: $scope.$parent.containerWidth